# When to release an instance variable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, memory-management

Basically I have this scenario going on:

```
//in interface header 
@property(nonatomic,retain)OtherClass *otherClass;

//implementation
- (id)initWithOtherClassInstance:(OtherClass*)otherClass
{ 
    if (self != [super init])
        return self;

         self.otherClass = otherClass;

    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    //Do I need to release otherClass ?
    [otherClass release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

I'm wondering whether I should release an instance variable on which not explicitly alloc, new or copy was called? The memory management guides say I shoud not, but what I'm worrying about is that `self.otherClass = otherClass` would retain the instance variable and thus cause a leak when I would decide to not release it in the `dealloc` method.

Moreover releasing the instance variable in the `dealloc` method does not generate an exception, which it would in case it was overreleased.

Does my reasoning here make any sense, and what is the best thing to do in a case like this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you do need to release this, as other answers suggest.  But I find that explicitly calling `[foo release]` on an ivar that you retained via property setter to be a little unbalanced.  I prefer setting `self.otherClass = nil;` in these scenarios.

Of course under the hood it will do a release for you, but it just looks more balanced and clean.

Comment: This gets into the religious debate about using property accessors in dealloc.

Comment: It's not a religious debate. Apple says not to. It is unquestionably preferred in Cocoa to release instead of using an accessor in `dealloc`. I don't personally like the way it is, but I don't see much room for disagreement when the docs specifically say one way or the other.

Comment: I've heard these suggestions, but it's not clear as to why.  Just because "Apple said so" to me isn't always a good enough reason (though it usually carries enough weight).

Comment: Can you please elaborate on why setting self.foo = nil would do the same thing as [foo release]. For me these are two different things, is setting self.foo = nil decrementing the retain count of self.foo as well ?

Comment: When you have a property with a declaration of retain (such as @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *foo;   This wraps the retain/release logic for you when you say self.foo = @"bar";  and self.foo = nil;   The value will be retained and released for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing this right, the rule you mentioned is the 'create' rule. You still need to match all your retains with releases as well.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

```
self.otherClass = otherClass
```

is the same as

```
[self setOtherClass:otherClass]
```

The default implementation on setOtherClass: looks like

```
- (void) setOtherClass:(OtherClass*)other
{
  [other retain];
  [otherClass release];
  otherClass = other;
}
```

As you can see, it retains the object, so you have to release it somewhere.

If you don't like explicit release without explicit alloc, new or copy, then you can do the next in dealloc:

```
- (void) dealloc
{
  [self setOtherClass:nil];
  [super dealloc];
}
```

Comment: Actually the default implementation of a property is simply to assign the instance variable.  The property needs to be a *retain* property for the implementation to look like your setter.

Comment: By the way, your setter has a bug in it.  If the argument other is the same as otherClass, you might be assigning a dealloc'd pointer.

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand you correctly. Default implementation depends on property attributes. The otherClass property is declared as retain, so the setter will retain object. If you don't like the default implementation, you can implement your own setter. What is wrong here?
And yes, my implementation is buggy, thanks for noticing. It was just an idea how it works;)

Comment: The default for a property unless you explicitly set `retain` or `copy` is assign.

Comment: Also, I hope you don't mind but I am going to take the liberty of fixing your set accessor.

Answer (score 0):

Your init method is wrong.  You need to assign the result of [super init] to self.

Other than that, assuming that self.otherClass is a retain property, what you have done is sort of OK.  If you insist on using the property in -init you should assign the property to nil in dealloc, as Ben says, because then whether the property is assign, retain or copy, the right thing will happen.

However,

it is recommended that you do not use accessors in the -init and -dealloc methods.  This is because subclasses may override them to do things you don't expect and KVO observers might get notified in dealloc.  So you should probably just set and retain the ivar in init and release it in dealloc.